# LibXML2.dylib with Xcode6

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, libxml2

I'm trying to **integrate libxml2.dylib** in my IOS project,I have linked this library in **Link binary with libraries** in Build phases for target,its working fine when I run it on simulator,but throws linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) **library not found for -lxml2** error **when trying to run it in device**,I have also added -lxml2 in Other Linker flags in Build settings,still couldn't get it done.I'm a beginner,any advice on this is highly appreciated.I'm using Xcode 6.1 and IOS SDK 8.1.

Comment: Try remove the `libxml2.dylib` and readd it.

Comment: @skyline75489 I tried that too,no luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

Just put /usr/include/libxml2 in your **Header Search Paths** on the **Target**.

I'm using XCode 6.1.1 and Yosemite.

Best regards.